# bitbake rootfs large for core image minimal

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, rootfs

First, I generated a `core-image-sato` target image using bitbake. Then after that I generated `core-image-minimal` target. The root file system generated still contains the contents/packages of the existing target.

How can I avoid this and have a minimal root file system

Comment: It is not how it works. Each image is build from package feed from scratch. It is not based on previous image.

Comment: If you have problem with disk usage, you can look [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#ref-classes-rm-work)

Comment: Will the sysroots folder will be deleted before starting a new image

Comment: On a recent Yocto version, yes

Comment: I am using Poky version 2.0.3

Comment: You should upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I think core-image-sato is build with `X11` and core-image-minimal is `without X11`. both are fully deferent images.

so in your `deploy/images/your-board/` .  should have `core-image-sato-*-rootfs-*` will present also `core-image-minimal-*-rootfs*` present.

Those things you can not delete if you delete core-image-sato-*-rootfs-* next time you can not able to compile core-image-sato. it will give errors.

Answer (score 0):

Did this in latest Poky 2.6 - Try to use poky > 2.1

bitbake core-image-minimal & bitbake core-image-sato 
generates different set of images.

[image: images created after bitbake]

- check if you have enough disk space!
- check that you are not adding extra packages in your /build/conf/local.config
- check that you are using different local.config files while bitbaking core-image-minimal and core-image-sato. (If you have added packages while bitbaking sato then those packages will be added while bitbaking minimal, if you are using same local.config)

Just a suggestion, not that you have to do it:
If you are bitbaking for the first time use default /build/conf/local.config and /build/conf/bblayers.conf
(uncommenting DL_DIR, SSTATE_DIR, TMPDIR will be beneficial though)